# PHP 5.6: What does "opcache: interned string buffers overflow" mean?

Tags: php

I am running PHP 5.6 and enabled the compiled-in module opcache.
Now when I read the warnings inside my error log, I get these messages every few milliseconds:

```
Warning Interned String buffer overflow
```

There is no description to this error using [this google search](https://www.google.de/search?sclient=psy-ab&btnG=Suche&q=opcache%20%22interned%20string%20buffer%20overflow%22). However, the source code says, there [may not be enough memory](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/opcache/ZendAccelerator.c#L348-L349)? Did I read this correctly?

So, to my understanding it is absolutely okay if cache gets exhausted and will be reused/recycled for new strings. If not, what am I missing?

I set `opcache.interned_string_buffer` from 4 to 8 MiB, but no luck yet.

Comment: What a fast edit, I had no chance. Nice, thanks. :-)

Comment: It may be worth while asking the chat section of StackOverflow too... Whilst it's not a programming issue, it's going to have effected programmers.

Answer (score 8):

> opcache.interned_strings_buffer - A pretty neat setting with like 0 documentation. PHP uses a technique called string interning to improve performance— so, for example, if you have the string "foobar" 1000 times in your code, internally PHP will store 1 immutable variable for this string and just use a pointer to it for the other 999 times you use it. Cool. This setting takes it to the next level— instead of having a pool of these immutable string for each SINGLE php-fpm process, this setting shares it across ALL of your php-fpm processes. It saves memory and improves performance, especially in big applications.

https://www.scalingphpbook.com/best-zend-opcache-settings-tuning-config/

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate the effects on my error "Warning Interned String buffer overflow" and how to find out which are sane values?

Comment: I think you should take a look at the opcache status page, where you will be able to see or you are out of memory. The solution then would be to increase those parameters in `php.ini` https://github.com/rlerdorf/opcache-status

Answer (score 1):

[There is an ongoing bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71135) that affects some users when opcache.interned_string_buffer is not set high enough. The bug causes Apache to crash so you would definitely know if you were experiencing the issue.

I recommend temporarily creating a php file such as info.php and adding

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

view the file in your browser to easily see "Interned Strings Used memory" and make sure you have some free memory. I have a fairly large wordpress site and I have my memory limit set at 32. I consistently have about 14mb interned strings memory used.